# href attribute conflicting with my css hover rule

Tags: html, css

How can I get EXAMPLE TWO to work like EXAMPLE ONE. Whenever I add an a href tag it completely breaks my css hover rule to turn the color red. Help.

```
<!-- EXAMPLE ONE -->
<a href="#"><div class="nav-portfolio">
    <div class="navstyle">portfolio</div>
            <div id="project-numbox">1</div>
             <div id="project-numbox">2</div>
             <div id="project-numbox">3</div>
</div></a>

<!-- EXAMPLE TWO -->
<div class="navigation-container">
<a href="#"><div class="nav-portfolio">
    <div class="navstyle">portfolio</div>
    <a id="test" href="#"><div id="project-numbox">1</div></a>
<a href="#"><div id="project-numbox">2</div></a>
<a href="#"><div id="project-numbox">3</div></a>
</div></a>
</div>
```

edit: css in jsfiddle link

**jsfiddle link: http://jsfiddle.net/jZWF7/1/**

Comment: You should be using a class instead of giving multiple elements the same id. Not changing your code, I added color:red; to #project-numbox. Though I'm not sure if that's exactly what you are looking for here

Comment: The first example doesn't have `<a>` tags to begin with.  What did you add `href` attributes to?

Comment: Have you tried your :hover on `.nav-portfolio` a rather than on `.nav-portfolio` ?

Comment: @Barmar If I add an a href to <div id="project-numbox">1</div>. the css hover does not work.

Comment: The problem isn't that you're adding an `href`.  It's that you're adding a new child element into the `div` in the 2nd example: `<a>`.  I believe the first two answers below will solve your issue.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Add the CSS:

```
.navigation-container a {
    color: inherit;
}
```

to override the default style of anchors.

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/barmar/jZWF7/6/)

Answer (score 1):

Add this CSS:

```
.nav-portfolio:hover a {
  color: red;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/jZWF7/7/

Answer (score 1):

In your second example you have nested `<a>` tags. An open `<a>` tag followed with another `<a>` before it's closed will automatically close it. So the second example actually looks like this:

```
<div class="navigation-container">
    <a href="#"></a>
    <div class="nav-portfolio">
        <a href="#"><div class="navstyle">portfolio</div></a>
        <a id="test" href="#"><div id="project-numbox">1</div></a>
        <a href="#"><div id="project-numbox">2</div></a>
        <a href="#"><div id="project-numbox">3</div></a>
    </div>
</div>
```

Removing the first `<a>` will fix your problem.